# I want to Set Scheduler at 9 AM Daily But It is not Working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, scheduler

I want to set scheduler at 9 Am Daily.
Following is my code but it is not working in java.
I used @Scheduler anotation for Scheduling My Job.

```
 @Scheduled(cron="0 0 9 * * ?")
    public void schedule4() {
        SendmailController();
    }

    public void SendmailController()
    {
        try {
            fEmailCtrl.sendScheduleWiseLeadToFinance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you debug if the `SendmailController()` method works? the method itself maybe invoked but the sendMail may not work,you can add some log to check

Comment: the class in which you have this function. is it a spring bean? Does it have any annotation on the top of the class?

Answer (score 0):

Is it a spring boot application then you need to add the annotation `@EnableScheduling` to enable scheduling.

Also can you print anything in the logs in the method: `schedule4()` to debug and see what is happening, is there any error produced in the method: `SendmailController()`

Answer (score 0):

You should tell your application to scan for scheduled anotations. Easiest way is to update your apllication context file with config such as this:

```
<task:annotation-driven scheduler="taskScheduler"/>
<task:scheduler id="taskScheduler" pool-size="X"/>
```